# loading strings with spaces as numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I would like to load a csv file as a numpy array. Each row contains string fields with spaces. 
I tried with both loadtxt() and genfromtxt() methods available in numpy. By default both methods consider space as a delimiter and separates each word in the string as a separate column. Is there anyway to load this sort of data using loadtxt() or genfromtxt() or will I have to write my own code for it?

Sample row from my file:

`826##25733##Emanuele Buratti## ##Mammalian cell expression`

Here ## is the delimiter and space denotes missing values.

Comment: Did you try to include the delimiter keyword in the call to np.loadtxt()? i.e. np.loadtxt(delimiter="##")

Comment: I made use of this `np.genfromtxt(trainFile, dtype = str, delimiter = '##', comments = '//', missing_values = ' ')` loadtxt follows similar syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that the default comments character `#` is conflicting with your delimiter.  I was able to load your data like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.loadtxt('/tmp/sample.txt', dtype=str, delimiter='##', comments=None)
array(['826', '25733', 'Emanuele Buratti', ' ', 'Mammalian cell expression'], 
      dtype='|S25')
```

You can see that the dtype has been automatically set to whatever the maximum length string was.  You can use `dtype=object` if that is troublesome.  As an aside, since your data is not numeric, I would probably recommend using `csv` module rather than numpy for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the csv equivalent, as wim suggested:

```
import csv

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='##')
    rows = list(reader)
```

As @wim pointed out the comments, this doesn't really work since the delimiter must be one character. So if you change the above so that `delimiter='#'`, you get this as the result:

```
[['826', '', '25733', '', 'Emanuele Buratti', '', ' ', '', 'Mammalian cell expression']]
```

Comment: Burhan, I think this will not work without pre-processing because csv delimiter must be a 1-character string.

Comment: Right you are @wim. Thanks; but with using a single `#` as the delimiter, you still get the desired results, except you have extra spaces in the list.